# Switched test database from SQLite to MySQL, now some tests fail because of differing IDs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rspec, database-cleaner

I used SQLite so far for testing my Rails app, and MySQL for development. This worked well with Rails 4.

Now I upgraded to Rails 5, and I wanted to execute `rake db:test:prepare`, which threw me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "ENGINE"
```

I took a look at my `schema.rb`, and noticed a lot of stuff in there that's not database agnostic:

```
create_table "findings", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci" do |t|
```

This seems to be a know issue: [Rails 5 schema.rb adding non-agnostic options. dev mysql -> test sqlite](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26209).

The proposed solution is to use the same adapter for both test and development, so I switched to MySQL for testing.

But now some of the specs fail - all of the have in common that they depend on specific IDs from the database. Here's a spec for `#container_for(@user)` which creates a `<div class="user" id="user_1">` for a user with ID 1:

```
describe '#container_for(object)' do
  subject { container_for(create(:user)) { 'Some content' } }

  it { should have_css 'div#user_1.user' }
  it { should have_content 'Some content' }
end
```

When running this spec alone, it passes. But when running it with the whole spec battery, it fails:

```
expected to find css "div#user_1.user" but there were no matches
```

I already used `DatabaseCleaner` gem with Rails 4 and SQLite which fixed problems like this, but this doesn't do it anymore, and I have no idea how to debug this further.

For the time being, I simply switched back to SQLite and manually removed all `options: "ENGINE=InnoDB ..."` from `schema.rb`. But I will have to do this again and again when changing the schema. Any help for a better solution (or instructions on how to fix/debug the problem) is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've never thought it an issue w/ unit tests that it is a problem to have a different underlying database, one often uses mock dbs, as the idea is you are testing the 'class-under-test', not the db, so I'd disagree with the Rails folks recommendation. (For development purposes, having same DB is a good idea though.) But back to point - can you swap out the schema.rb when running your tests with the SQLLite Version?

Comment: Good chance you've already thought about it but why not fix the specs to not depend on the id? it {should have_css "div#user_#{user.id}.user" }"

Comment: Joel's point is good - seems like there is something wrong with your setup/teardown script: "When running this spec alone, it passes. But when running it with the whole spec battery, it fails:"

Comment: @Joel_Blum is on the right track. You should never assume that `id`s will be anything other than unique-per-database. Also, if you're not developing, testing, and deploying with the same database then you're bobbing for apples in a barrel full of fish hooks, possibly while on fire. So don't do that to yourself.

Comment: Yes you're right, I shouldn't depend on the IDs. I can fix that. But still I'd like to find out where the problem with the setup/teardown script. Can you give me some hint, @michaelok?

Comment: One possibility is that there is some ordering difference how it used to work and how it works now. For example, there could be a rollback that is rolling back the transaction that created user1. It would be helpful if you could post more details like the DatabaseCleaner strategy, how the tests are configured, etc.